How to normalise note lengths when analysing music
I am analysing baroque music obtained from midi files and I would like to make make timing comparisons. (Yes, I know that midi is far from ideal, but it is the only source that I have.)
A given piece can be written in different ways, for example in BWV565

the final D is sometimes written as a quaver:

sometimes as a crotchet tied to a minim:

sometimes as a semiquaver:

When comparing two pieces of music, I need a way to compare timings in a uniform manner.
A midi file usually has a tempo, so I can calculate the length of a crotchet in seconds, but a crotchet in a tempo of 60 has the same length as a minim in a tempo of 120.
Arbitrarily defining a crotchet as a note that lasts half-a-second won't work: When I encounter a piece with a tempo of 90, few (undotted) notes will be close to 0.5 seconds.
How can I resolve this problem?

so you want to calculate their beat values without tempo yeah? in that case you can do away with the tempo all together, check out my answer

Are these MIDI files made with a music notation program, or are they recordings of a musician playing?

What are the specific pieces? It seems strange that there is a midi file but no available score. How was that midi encoded without a score? Have you looked in imslp.org for scores?

You should just use the tempo of the midi and the piece to fix this discrepancy. MIDI files can be made in one of two ways. Either, it's a result of a recording (and the 'real tempo' won't quite match up the file's set tempo, or it's even set to default), or it's notated by hand (in which case the tempo will likely match up to some multiple of the real tempo).
Your examples aren't even that bad. I've seen MIDI's obtained from recordings of pieces at 143 bpm that were set to 60 bpm, the notes were all over the place. Even these are easily fixable though, read below;

In the end, you'll have 3 bpm values:

The bpm when you play the midi file and tap through manually.
The bpm that is in the midi file (in microseconds per quarter note).
The bpm indicated by the score.

Transposing a piece to double the tempo with half the note values creates exactly the same piece to a computer.
(To a human, there is typically a difference to a 2/4ths march at 80 bpm vs. a 4/4/ths piece at 160 bpm, the player will use different emphasis)
If you have a real score to compare against, then you know the real tempo. Obtain the ratio between the midi file's tempo and the notated or played one (or close to) using a list of tempi;
Typical note durations of the primary note in a piece (can be a quaver or semiquaver) are, in 60ths of a second (or 'bpm'). Note that Adagio and Largo have exchanged places in baroque music:
Grave       ~  20-34  'solemn'
Adagio      ~  35-49  'very slow'
Largo/Lento ~  50-69  'slow'
Andante     ~  70-99  'gradual'
Moderato    ~ 100-119 'moderate'
Allegro     ~ 120-159 'lively'
Vivace      ~ 160-189 'fast'
Presto      ~ 190-229 'very fast'
Prestissimo/vivacissimamente/etc. 230+ 'extreme speed'

There are some 'in between' tempi and indicators. Outside using italian terms for 'little' (piu / poco) or 'much' (molto), indicating you should be at the lower end / upper end of a fast tempo or upper end / lower end of a slow tempo, the sheet music may indicate two tempi like allegro moderato, which would mean exactly 120 bpm (the boundary).
Then you find this ratio between real tempo and midi tempo. Baroque is typically played a tempo except for fermatas. In a recorded midi from a performance, these will show as longer notes in the notation software, and will mess up the score beyond them. So will ritardando/ritenuto. You'd need to look them up and fix them. Even without the original score, it's typically easy to see how long one should be, given their prevalence at the end of sections; typically a fermata will end a bar number 0 modulo 4.
Once you have your ratio, say r = 0.5, then you can multiply all note lengths by note_len[i] <= note_len[i] * r, and divide your tempo by tempo <= tempo_midi / r. Then the files become directly comparable. I do not recommend modifying 'ticks per beat'.
Most MIDI software will have a function to do this (just search google for 'multiply note lengths' and the name of your software). Alternatively you can write some code to modify the binary file yourself. You'll want to find all the delays, multiply/divide the number of 'ticks' for each, then round. Always use the original file as a source, don't multiply twice or you'll get compounding rounding errors. If your guess was off, re-do the modification from the original file. Here are some resources for midi file encoding: faydoc, mcgill, teragon. A word of warning; Due to the ancient nature of the file format (computer programmers of the 1980s had to scrooge every little byte of memory) and the nature of design by committee, it's very esoteric.
MIDI files have a bunch of limitations. The two relevant limitations for classical music are the low number of tracks1 (16) making orchestral pieces sometimes impossible to fit in a midi file, and the low 'ticks' per whole note (typically 240 or 384)2 which can make some complex pieces hard to notate. Notice how this number is 2*2*2*2*3*5 = 240 and 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*3 = 384, which means 64ths and smaller notes are a very low number of ticks.
In fact, when playing very slow pieces with fast flourishes or odd divisions (common in classical, much rarer in modern music), (older) MIDI notation software's rigid limitations on ticks per beat (240, 384, etc.) means that the passages can get awfully distorted/stilted sounding. To fix this, the file creator can deliberately pick a higher tempo than the original to mask this problem. I suspect your crotchet-minim version of the toccata uses this trick to improve the precision. If the file is intended to be played (as most are), not printed, there's no issue with this. With higher tempi comes higher fidelity, at the cost of lower max length. (Although this value is 0x0FFFFFFF = 2^28-1, some 194 hours at 240 bpm).
Optionally (depending on what kind of analysis you're doing) you may have to 'fix' (modify) any fermatas afterwards, because their lengths are chosen by the player, and may vary greatly from performance to performance.
You should end up with neat notation.
Note 1: that this limitation comes from the protocol. While you can create a file with more than 16 tracks, it's technically not a valid midi for use with a synthesizer, and won't reproduce exactly. Suppose you put two pianos on one track, and hit middle C at the same time. The synth will only play one middle C and ignore the other, because it will receive two simultaneous time=0:00:05:00 channel=0 action=noteOn pitch=C4 volume=64 calls.
Channel 10 is typically used for drums as well, and is a fixed "instrument", with each of the 128 "notes" a different drum sample.
Note 2: Varies by software, but 384 is the most widely supported number by older systems and programs. I've mostly written this by memory and back in the day you could not edit this value. Some programs may even assume it.

I'm unclear if you are claiming the resolution of a MIDI file is fixed to 384 ticks per quarter note or 384 ticks per whole note (96 ticks per quarter note), but either way, that is probably a requirement or default of the software you are using. The resolution of a MIDI file can be 1 to 32767 ticks per quarter note and is typically a multiple of 24 up to about 1920. (There is also a resolution format that uses frames per second and ticks per frame, but it is not used often, and I think most MIDI file software doesn't support it.)

A MIDI file can have more than 16 tracks, but a MIDI file that sends to one MIDI device can only use 16 MIDI channels. Usually one channel is for drums, so you are limited to drums and 15 other instrument sounds. Some MIDI file software has a limit of 16 tracks, but if you only care about notation, you might use software that allows more tracks and not care what channels or instrument sounds are used. (A MIDI file that sends to multiple MIDI devices is technically possible, but I think MIDI file software support for multi-device MIDI files is mixed, and most MIDI files use only one device.)

Compare them by looking at the ratio of durations within each piece; it should not be necessary to assign specific note values to specific durations at all.  For your sanity and that of your programmers, you can arbitrarily use note durations in your code, but it shouldn't matter whether you call something a crotchet or a minim as long as you also call the thing with one fourth the duration a semiquaver or a quaver, respectively.
The information you want just isn't present in midi files; if it were, it would stand a good chance of being incorrect, and there are even contexts in which two instances of a melody will be notated using different note values, yet you will want to be able to identify them with one another.
You can also have a function, of course, that looks at similarity of absolute duration, such that the same sequence of intervals with the same relative durations may be considered more similar if the absolute durations are also more similar.
As far as BWV 565 is concerned, it's not clear what your purpose is, but you should be aware that the first two modern examples given in the question are probably entirely without any authoritative justification.  The last example matches the manuscript; the first two don't.  This may or may not matter to you depending on what you're doing.
Another thing to keep in mind is that MIDI is above all a mechanism for encoding performance data rather than notation.  Any midi file derived from an actual performance is likely to have different durations for notes of the same value, and indeed it's possible that the first two examples were created that way: the tendency to hold a note longer than its nominal duration will be the greatest for notes that fall at the end of a phrase.  Depending on your source for the files -- and especially if the files are created by random hobbyists who've posted them to the internet -- these problems will be difficult indeed.  It is probably impossible to reverse engineer notation from a performance of a piece in free time such as a toccata, even if you ignore the question of which power of two to assign to a given note duration.

that depends if you are looking at comparing the duration in seconds of each note or the relative note value / beat type.
to give them integer values, given a decent range of values (whole note to 1/64th note value) and including dotted and triplets (anything like double dotted or groupings other than triplets you can work out) can be represented by integers (whole numbers) if a whole note = 384.
 whole             triplet x2/3          dotted x3/2
1/ 1*384 = 384    1/ 1*2/3*384 = 256    1/ 1*3/2*384 = 576
1/ 2*384 = 192    1/ 2*2/3*384 = 128    1/ 2*3/2*384 = 288
1/ 4*384 = 96     1/ 4*2/3*384 = 64     1/ 4*3/2*384 = 144
1/ 8*384 = 48     1/ 8*2/3*384 = 32     1/ 8*3/2*384 = 72
1/16*384 = 24     1/16*2/3*384 = 16     1/16*3/2*384 = 36
1/32*384 = 12     1/32*2/3*384 = 8      1/32*3/2*384 = 18
1/64*384 = 6      1/64*2/3*384 = 4      1/64*3/2*384 = 9

examples from the question

minum = 1/2 = 192
crotchet = 1/4 = 96
crotchet tied to a minum = (1/4 + 1/2) * 384 = 288
quaver = 1/8 = 48
semiquaver = 1/16 = 24

that's easiest for me if you're going from a score
@phoog answer covers alot of what i'm about to say next
if you're going off a midi file then there's alot to consider, depends on the division word in the file header chunk, that can be set to tell you what the value of a quarter note is. if you don't understand data chunks or know what a 16bit word is then we're off track in this paragraph, you can ignore this paragraph.
really need to know if you intend on comparing with tempo or not. if you don't care about tempo, then you're relying on the score from the midi file to be as intended by the composer, and that's probably not going to happen. if you have the original score, use the system i use in this answer.
if you have the SMPTE timings, just use those values to compare, you don't need to convert it to a score and then analyze crotchets for example.
